# Renormalization of composite operators in gauge theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, yang-mills

I am trying to understand, how composite operators in gauge theory are renormalized.
In this paper the authors consider the renormalization of Yang-Mills stress-energy tensor:

$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(1)} [A] = -F_{\mu \sigma}^{a} F_{\nu \sigma}^{a}
-g_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}_0 [A] 
$$

In the second section it is mentioned that if one considers a set of gauge invariant operators $\{\mathcal{O}^{GI} [A]\}$ of a given dimension $D$ and Lorentz transformation properties, than during the process of renormalization the operator from $\{\mathcal{O}^{GI} [A]\}$ will mix with the other operators from $\{\mathcal{O}^{GI} [A]\}$ with the appropriate dimension and Lorentz transformation properties and gauge non-invariant operators $\{\mathcal{O}^{GNI} [A]\}$. This seems rather strange, because one encounters a sum of gauge-invariant and non-invariant operator ,which have different properties with respect to gauge group.

Then in the third section there is given an expression for the only operator that is gauge non-invariant and can mix with the energy-momentum tensor.
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(2)} [A] = \frac{\delta S}{\delta A_\mu^{a} (x)} A_\nu^{a} (x) + (\mu \leftrightarrow \nu) - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} \frac{\delta S}{\delta A_{\rho}^{a} (x)}  A_{\rho} (x)
$$

Then they claim that the renormalization matrix is a $2 \times 2$ matrix of the following structure:
$$
Z = 
\begin{pmatrix}
z_{11} (a, \varepsilon^{-1}, \eta) & z_{12} (a, \varepsilon^{-1}, \eta) \\
0 & z_{22} (a, \varepsilon^{-1}, \eta)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $\varepsilon$ - is $4 - d$, and $\eta$ - gauge-fixing parameter.

And the first question is :

Why does the $\mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(1)}$ mix with  $\mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(2)}$,
whereas $\mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(2)}$ does not receive contribution from $\mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(1)}$ ?

Then they claim that the combination $\mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(1)} + \mathcal{O}_{\mu \nu}^{(2)}$ yield finite correlation functions at zero momentum, therefore, the resulting operator would be the correct renormalized stress-energy tensor.

But so far, the reasoning seems a bit *ad hoc* and hard for me to follow.

The standard textbooks in QFT have a nice discussion on remormalization of coupling constants, mass e.t.c. But the question of dealing with composite operators seems to be a more advanced topic. I would be grateful if someone provided with the accessible or a simple example with renormalization of a composite operator.

Comment: A good starting point for composite operators and their renormalisation is the Collins book `Renormalization' which has a chapter dedicated to these.  If I remember correctly the discussion focuses on scalar theories, but there is also a chapter on gauge theories.   Another good reference is W. Zimmerman Annals of Physics 77 536-569 (1973) and Annals of Physics 77 570-601 (1973), although again the focus is on scalar theories.

Comment: @Wakabaloola thank you!